# How do I tell Jenkins to keep the Android SDK between builds?

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

### Problem

I'm setting up an Android Jenkins pipeline job. To build, it needs to have the Android SDK installed in the environment somewhere. It also has to keep the SDK updated.

### Solution

I run `android update sdk` in a pre-build stage in my `Jenkinsfile`.

### Caveat and remaining issue

This works great, **but the entire update is run every build (10+ minutes)** because the SDK is evidently being downloaded to a location where it's getting blown away between builds. How/where should I store the SDK so that it persists between builds (making the runs where the SDK is already up-to-date faster)?

Here's the snippet from my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage('Update Android SDK') {
       withEnv(['SHARED_HOME=/Users/Shared',
                'ANDROID_HOME=$SHARED_HOME/android-sdk-macosx',
                'PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH'
       ]) {
            sh 'echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform,tool,platform-tool,extra-android-m2repository'
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System
2. Check "Environment variables"
3. add name: ANDROID_HOME, value -> your android sdk dir example /var/jenkins/tools/android-sdk
4. click "add"

personally i do it in this way.
and it is working fine , all jobs using the same SDK.

**Option 1:**
using [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin)
it will download the SDK automatically for you, into this directory 
**/var/jenkins/tools/android-sdk**

and then i add the Environment variable as i mentioned early.

**Option 2:**

Download the SDK manually and then i add the Environment variable as i mentioned early.

Comment: Tried option 2 basically, but with the Jenkins Pipeline as I mentioned. The issue is that the SDK keeps redownloading packages that it downloaded in previous jobs, even if I put things in /Users/Shared/android-sdk-macosx. I'll try putting it in /var/ like you and report back.

Comment: i had the same problem previously every time i run new job it start downloading again.
but when i put it in this dir /var/ it works fine.